# case statement in sql?

Tags: sql

I have table called Employee.Employee table has
`ID,Name,DOB,DOJ,Designation columns`.In sp want to show like this
when input para's value is 1 select DOB in select clause as well as in where clause else use DOJ
Here is my query.I am able to manage in select clause but not in where clause.

```
select Name,Designation ,case when @value = 1 then DOB else DOJ end  from Employee
where DOB >='06/01/2015' and DOB < dateadd(dd,1,'06/01/2015')
```

If @val is other than 1,want to use DOJ in select and where clause.

Comment: case expression, not case statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the `CASE` in a Derived Table, a smart optimizer should be able to resolve this to either `DOB` or `DOJ`:

```
select *
from
 (
   select Name,Designation,
      case when @value = 1 then DOB else DOJ end as dt
   from Employee
 ) as dt
where dt >='06/01/2015' and dt < dateadd(dd,1,'06/01/2015')
```

Answer (score 1):

For the WHERE clause, it's probably easiest to just use two distinct tests:

```
((@value = 1 AND DOB >='06/01/2015' and DOB < dateadd(dd,1,'06/01/2015')) 
OR
(@value <> 1 AND DOJ >='06/01/2015' and DOJ < dateadd(dd,1,'06/01/2015')))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head

```
... WHERE (@val = 1 AND DOB = '...') OR (@val = 0 AND DOJ = '...') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

ends up in poor performance maybe but this should do the trick:

```
select  Name,Designation ,case when @value = 1 then DOB else DOJ end  
from    Employee
where   case when @value = 1 then DOB else DOJ end >='06/01/2015' 
        and case when @value = 1 then DOB else DOJ end < dateadd(dd,1,'06/01/2015')
```

you can use the same case-when block in your where clause...

Comment: If you use BETWEEN only one case expression is needed.

Comment: if DOB or DOJ would be DATE columns (or you cast them to DATE) it would be possible to check if they are equal. Like CAST(DOJ AS DATE) = '2015-01-06'..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Has it met your requirement?.

```
select Name,Designation ,case when @value = 1 then DOB else DOJ end  from Employee
where  WHERE (@val = 1 AND DOB >='06/01/2015') OR (@val <> 1 AND DOJ < dateadd(dd,1,'06/01/2015'))
```

Comment: No Chirag not like that.If value of input para is 2,still it will compare with DOB

Comment: @JuiTest I have modified the answer, Thank you.